# Inkscape - How to "apply" mirror path effect?

Tags: inkscape

In the computer software Blender, there is an apply button when using a mirror. When you have pressed that, you can change one side of the previously mirrored object and the other stays the same. How do I do this when using a mirror symmetry - path effect in Inkscape?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To turn the results of path-effects into actual paths you can edit, you use 'Path → Object to Path'.

Note, however, that this will apply all path-effects at once, if you have added multiple to the object and if your source object was a rectangle, circle, star etc., it will be converted to a path as well.

'Path → Split Path' will totally separate the path.